# Запуск тестов в одном браузере python + selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Стало интересно можно ли запустить несколько тестов в одной сессии браузера? Нашел параметризацию в PyTest, создал параметры в файле conftest.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в файле test_auth создал 2 теста на авторизацию и выход из аккаунта и каждому тесту передал фикстуру. По итогу переменные driver и url всё равно нужно инициализировать в файле с тестом + после запуска тестов, запускается 3 сессии( 1- с нужным мне url, и 2 абсолютно пустых), соответственно и тесты тоже падают. Кто нибудь может подсказать, что я делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите [pytest-selenium](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-selenium) и не пытайтесь городить велосипед

Comment: selenium - морально устарел давно. Советую присмотреться к питонячей реализации PlayWright, сильно облегчите себе жизнь и сэкономите кучу нервов и времени. https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro

Селениум весь на костылях и косяках. Нет смысла сним работать давно уже